# Django CheckBox Form Item using choices not true / false (Boolean)

Tags: django, forms

This is driving me bonkers and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction to change this.  I've got a Boolean item in my Model, however when I create my form it gives a Choice option with "Unknown", "Yes" and "No".  I thought it would default to "True" and "False" so need to change this accordingly.  My initial thought was to use a Widget (like I've done to set Textarea's up, but cannot seem to find a model or widget .boolean option.  If anyone can steer me right I'd really appreciate it :)

Code below incase its of use, I'm only 2 months into learning Django / Python (in my spare time which isn't a lot with a 4 month old) so the code may not be as good as someone with a lot of experience.

Thanks in advance :)

Model

```
class Announcement(models.Model):
    announcement_title = models.CharField(max_length=75, verbose_name="Announcement Title")
    announcement_text = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Announcement Text")
    announcement_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Announcement Active")
    announcement_date = models.DateField(default=date.today, verbose_name="Announcement Date")
    announcement_high = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Announcement Alert Severity")
    announcement_expiry = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name="Announcement Expiry")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.announcement_text
```

Form

```
class AnnouncementForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Announcement
        exclude = ('announcement_date', 'announcement_active', )
        help_texts = {
            'announcement_title': _('Enter a title to give the announcement.'),
            'announcement_text': _('Type the announcement body in this box.'),
            'announcement_expiry': _('Can specify a date to stop displaying the announcement. Can be left blank.'),
            'announcement_high': _('Tick this box to indicate a red severity, un-ticked will make it yellow.'),
        }
        widgets = {
            'announcement_title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'announcement_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'cols': 80, 'rows': 10}),
            'announcement_expiry': widgets.DateInput(attrs={'class' : 'datepicker'}),
        }
```

View

Quite big so not sure if this is needed. Can post if required.

Template

```
<form action="/siteadmin/{{ branding.dataset }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for item in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">
        {% if item.help_text %}
            <img src="/static/images/info.png" height="20" width="20" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="popover" title="{{ item.help_text }}">&nbsp
        {% endif %}
            {{ item.label_tag }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            {{ item }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="form-group">    
        <div class="col-sm-11">
            <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" value="Add" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

Comment: Which `BooleanField` is this happening on? have you recently made changes to your model (do you need to migrate)?

Comment: Sorry, good point.  Its announcement_high.  I did have some migrations that I failed to apply but not for that table.  I've made and migrated now and the POST data is still showing 'announcement_high' u'on'

Comment: I'll gladly add this as an answer if this turns out to be correct but I'm not sure.. the docs for [BooleanField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield) state " If you want to include a boolean in your form that can be either True or False (e.g. a checked or unchecked checkbox), you must remember to pass in required=False when creating the BooleanField."

Comment: Added required=False to my model and ran makemigrations; "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'"

Comment: What version of django? can you please update your question with the code you tried

Comment: announcement_high = models.BooleanField(required=False, default=True, verbose_name="Announcement Alert Severity")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84048/discussion-between-sayse-and-smurf).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean about there not being a widget option. You define widgets for boolean fields just like you do for any other fields: in the form definition.

```
class AnnouncementForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Announcement
        ...
        widgets = {
            'announcement_title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'announcement_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'cols': 80, 'rows': 10}),
            'announcement_expiry': widgets.DateInput(attrs={'class' : 'datepicker'}),
            'announcement_high': forms.CheckboxInput()
        }
```

Comment: tried that but get;Exception Value:  
'module' object has no attribute 'CheckboxInput'

Comment: the POST data i get back from my form shows; announcement_high u'on', instead of true. This means that form.is_valid() fails and throws an exception.  This is the issue I'm trying to overcome at the moment.  Someone on IRC suggested CBV but I'd like to understand this problem and then CBV is the next chapter of the book I'm reading to learn Django.

Comment: But that is why you use forms instead of accessing the raw POST data. `form.cleaned_data['announcement_high']` will be True or False.

Comment: Hi @daniel-roseman.  Thanks for the continued replies.  I believe you've replied to me in the past, thank you.  I'm not really trying to access the raw data, I'm just trying to troubleshoot why form.is_valid() is failing and assumed it was because the field is returning on.  I must admit, not sure what form.clean_data does, will go and read about it over lunch.